# find database which tables have certain word in a column name

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT column_name,
   TABLE_NAME
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%image%';
```

This code works, and it's showing the column and table name which have column name that in the title has image. But since I have a very complex system, and a lot of databases, I want to find database name also so, I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
 SELECT column_name,
   TABLE_NAME,
   DATABASE
 FROM   information_schema.columns
 WHERE  column_name LIKE '%image%';
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The column you are looking for is `TABLE_SCHEMA`. See the documentation for more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html